# IntelliJ 2017.1.2 GOLANG debug does not work on breakpoints in packages

Tags: go, intellij-idea, delve

My application is made up of one main.go file and a handful of packages. When hitting breakpoints within the main.go, IntelliJ works as expected, showing variable values etc., however, when a breakpoint is set in a different package - aside from it being hit, no variables are shown and step over/in features do not work as expected (ignored when hit). Has anyone run into this issue and if so is there a workaround?