# Cannot set breakpoint in golang packages in Intellij 2020.1

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland, delve

I have a simple web app which has cmd/ and pkg/ folders. As a convention, I'm importing packages in *.go files in cmd folder. Setting breakpoints work fine in any file in cmd but it doesn't work in packages.

Error message is:

```
could not find statement at <path_to_file>:<line_number>, please use a line with a statement
```

Project structure I'm using is similar to this in simplified form:

```
project_root:
- cmd/
    main.go 
- pkg/
    app.go // I set a breakpoint to a function here L:156. it's being called at main.go
    ...
- api/
- config/
...
```

[image]

my build flag has `-gcflags "all=-N -l"`

Similar issue has been discussed here in the past: [IntelliJ 2017.1.2 GOLANG debug does not work on breakpoints in packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851853/intellij-2017-1-2-golang-debug-does-not-work-on-breakpoints-in-packages)

Edit:

- added project structure
- added screenshot of the line with breakpoint

Comment: Please provide more details about the error (screenshot of it would be great). Also, sample code to replicate this would be useful.

Comment: Make sure the function where you put breakpoint is used in compiled code (unused functions are optimized away). If you are debugging remotely the problem can be in file path mismatch. IDE logs can clear this out.

Comment: thanks for the comments. It is a local debugging and I'm not trying to connect to any remote.

Comment: Thanks @neverov, your comment fixed this issue for me! I put a breakpoint in a function which I then realized wasn't really referenced anywhere (it wasn't obvious due to some function-pointer manipulations in the function which was supposed to invoke it)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your breakpoint method be used. I meet the same problem like you. And I find my bug (the breakpoint method never be used).